# Show that $\text{Null}\begin{bmatrix}\vec{a}^T \\ \vec{b}^T \\ \vec{c}^T\end{bmatrix}=\text{Null}\begin{bmatrix}\vec{a}^T \\ \vec{b}^T \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Show that if  $\{\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is lineary dependent but $\{\vec{a},\vec{b}\}$ is lineary independent. Then $$\text{Null}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
           \vec{a}^T \\
           \vec{b}^T \\
           \vec{c}^T
         \end{bmatrix}\right)=\text{Null}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
           \vec{a}^T \\
           \vec{b}^T 
         \end{bmatrix}\right)$$

My try:

We know that $\alpha_1\vec{a}+\alpha_2\vec{b}=0 \iff \alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$

And $\beta_1\vec{a}+\beta_2\vec{b}+\beta\vec{c}=0$ with at least one $\beta_i\neq0$

By definition of null space we know that $\begin{bmatrix}
           \vec{a}^T \\
           \vec{b}^T \\
           \vec{c}^T
         \end{bmatrix}\vec{x}=\vec{0}$

Then $$a^T\vec{x}=0$$ $$b^T\vec{x}=0$$ $$c^T\vec{x}=0$$

Adding up the first and second equation: $$a^T\vec{x}+b^T\vec{x}=0$$ but I'm not sure on how to apply the linear independence hypothesis

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b$ are l.i., but not $a,b,c$, then
$$c = \alpha_1 a + \alpha_2 b$$

If $x$ satisfies $x a = x b = 0$, then $x c = (\alpha_1 x a + \alpha_2 x b) = 0$. So the nullspaces must coincide.